# Immutable Map of dates

Tags: redux, immutable.js

I have Immutable Map with key as dates and value array of hours. On first call redux action return state.mergeDeep(response), everythink looks good, on update hours of this days too, but when i want to add more dates to this map i get a lot of rerenders. 
Its looks weird coz when i on update return state.set('2017-11-01', ['12:00']) its ok but return state.set('2018-01-01, ['12:00']) call update view.

Response example:

`response = {
    '2017-12-01':['10:00', '11:00],
    '2017'12-02':['10:00'],
    .
    .
    .
    '2017-12-30':[10:00],
}`

WhyDidYouUpdate package log:

```
MyComponent.props.myData._root.nodes.11.nodes.1.entry.1._root.array.0.ownerID

MyComponent.props.myData._root.nodes.8.nodes.0.entry.1._root.array
```

I do not know what can I do

EDIT:

```js
class TestContainer extends PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.firstCall('2017-12-01');
  }

  @autobind
  onChangeDate(date: string) {
    this.props.updateCall(date);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.onChangeDate('2018-01-01')} />
    );
  }
}


function mapStateToProps(state: Object): Object {
  return {
    myData: state.myData,
  };
}

function mapDispachToProps(dispatch): Object {
  return bindActionCreators({...myDataActions}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispachToProps)(TestContainer);
```

Comment: Please show your components code, beacuse now we can only geuss

Comment: i have container connected to storage with simple empty component with button which call action, both purecomponents.

Comment: Please edit anser and paste your code

Comment: It looks ok, if the data has been changed then the view should refresh, i dont know where is problem

Comment: If u use why-did-you-update package it logs for you useless rerenders components with same properties etc. in my console its looks like this https://imgur.com/a/nqpaC

Comment: Do you send other data to the component? Please show the component call

Comment: Are you sure `Immutable.mergeDeep()` is doing what you expect? Lists are merged by index position. You didn't share your reducer code.